# Sending emails from a python script

Tags: python, email, smtp, python-unittest, smtplib

I am working on writing a python test using unittest and selenium webdriver to test if our server is down, and to send an email to notify me if it is not. I am currently working on implementing just the email functionality. This is my current code. When run, the program seems to run, but never ends, and never sends the email. (i.e. in the command line the program seems as though it is running as it doesn't give any errors and you have to escape the "running" program before you can enter another command).
My current code is:

```
 #tests for if server is up and notifies if it is not
    import unittest
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import os
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
    import smtplib
    
    
    class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):
    
            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            server.login("email@gmail.com", "password")
            msg = "Testing if server is down" 
            server.sendmail("email@gmail.com", "email@gmail.com", msg)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

I am unsure why this does  not work, and would appreciate any insight. Thank you!

## Edit

When changing the code as suggested, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testServerIsUp.py", line 14, in <module>
    class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):
  File "testServerIsUp.py", line 18, in PythonOrgSearch
    server.starttls() #and this method to begin encryption of messages
  File "C:\Users\663255\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 751, in starttls
    "STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start a conversation with the mail server and enable encryption:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls() #and this method to begin encryption of messages
server.login("email@gmail.com", "password")
msg = "Testing if server is down" 
server.sendmail("email@gmail.com", "email@gmail.com", msg)
```

Since the `smtplib.SMTP()` call was not successful, you can try `SMTP_SSL` on port 465:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login("email@gmail.com", "password")
msg = "Testing if server is down" 
server.sendmail("email@gmail.com", "email@gmail.com", msg)
```

Comment: it still does not work, with the same problem. After I ran it like that, I thought maybe it needed a server.close() to fix it, but that did not work either. Any advice?

Comment: This gave me a traceback error. I added the full error as an edit to the post to preserve formatting.

Comment: Try running the second option without the `server.ehlo()` method.

Comment: I then get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testServerIsUp.py", line 14, in <module>
    class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):
  File "testServerIsUp.py", line 17, in PythonOrgSearch
    server.starttls() #and this method to begin encryption of messages
  File "C:\Users\663255\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 751, in starttls
    "STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.

Comment: I don't think it will let me use the ehlos or the starttls extensions

Comment: Yes, it appears that your server does not support TLS. Try again with the code in the second option. I just updated it.

Comment: using that, i now get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testServerIsUp.py", line 14, in <module>
    class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):
  File "testServerIsUp.py", line 16, in PythonOrgSearch
    server.login("*email*@gmail.com", "*password*")

Comment: File "C:\Users\663255\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 729, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "C:\Users\663255\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 720, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "C:\Users\663255\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 641, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14

Comment: <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt6\n5.7.14 gLbxU1Ehq_ECXL8x_PYMS0hG0YqkcDs0W_UcWzavLp3ibGxph546EIW8t-OcRVfpHd8VBe\n5.7.14 L5efltMyAKr8gn1P39BrxXkdsndclayHX34I0N_aApXMPcb2as5i1fPbGf-a8PL667wnEf\n5.7.14 cKbT_EZYQlVNQPxQZDjBoAjQnpt9-Cy6qFdffAftGEIqwvnHNObDwqqXdxldyAW_NsrAaU\n5.7.14 ry8E2W0DqffsWvfXj11euYwH6P8qI> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 m127sm2517844pfc.37 - gsmtp')

Comment: wait nevermind. It's because google blocked the sign in attempt. As soon as i allowed access to less secure apps it worked, so that was the issue. Your last way actually did work.

Comment: Ok, great! Glad to help!